# Mezzanine web content language translations

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have been looking for documentation and information as to how to translate web site content?

We've been using Django CMS for a long time and it gives us two tabs in the admin, i.e : English, Francais and we can toggle between the two to write content in the specific language.

In Mezzanine, I have my `LANGUAGES` tuple set up with en,fr as well as `USE_I18N = True` but I don't see how my content editors will be able to create bilingual pages. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mezzanine doesn't support multiple languages by default as Django-CMS does. You need to use 3th party app that can translate models which code you can't touch like [django-modeltranslation](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

There is an open issue for Mezzanine about Multilanguage support https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/106

I was created two multilingual sites with my custom app https://github.com/vstoykov/django-magic-translation